# Dynamically changing overflow property causes re-render

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

Is it possible to prevent the "auto scroll" to top event happening whenever you dynamically switch from `overflow:hidden` to `overflow:auto`?

Here's a demo of the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6v9nyc. If you scroll down to the end and click on the **Toggle nested scrollbar** button, you automatically get taken back to the top of the page.

I don't want this to happen. I want to remain at the same scroll position.

Here's my code:

**app.component.css**

```
.showcase-no-scrollbar {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.showcase-scrollbar {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: calc(100vh - 115px) !important;
  overscroll-behavior: none;
}

.showcase-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.31rem;
  background: #f9fbfd;
}

.showcase-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #959da5 !important;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="navbar">For your reading pleasure</div>
<div
  class="container-fluid showcase"
  [ngClass]="showScrollbar ? 'showcase-no-scrollbar' : 'showcase-scrollbar'"
>
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div
      class="col-9"
      [attr.data-cy]="'showcase'"
      [ngClass]="showScrollbar ? 'showcase-scrollbar' : 'showcase-no-scrollbar'"
    >
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ultrices
      tellus id magna maximus porta. Fusce pretium nibh nisl, sodales elementum
      nisi tincidunt at. Maecenas est tellus, dignissim et mattis sed, dictum et
      ex. Nunc purus nisl, tristique eu mi mollis, interdum pretium leo. Cras
      venenatis dui at tellus porttitor, sed pulvinar nibh posuere. Duis
      placerat sapien eu leo pulvinar, sit amet convallis tellus finibus. Ut et
      ipsum et nibh feugiat tempor. Phasellus vehicula arcu sit amet velit
      maximus, ac ullamcorper enim auctor. Praesent at condimentum nisl. Fusce
      ultricies massa luctus, imperdiet erat vitae, sagittis erat. Nullam
      gravida, libero a auctor condimentum, metus magna feugiat erat, eget
      ullamcorper diam justo in ipsum. Mauris neque mauris, congue a
      pellentesque a, molestie non turpis. Suspendisse at tincidunt libero.
      Nulla vitae est commodo, sodales metus sit amet, sodales urna. Quisque ex
      urna, luctus eu ultricies nec, imperdiet ac enim. Vestibulum tincidunt
      rutrum mi, id pharetra nunc sodales nec. Aliquam vulputate metus eros, ac
      rutrum magna venenatis id. Fusce dictum malesuada suscipit. Quisque luctus
      consequat venenatis. Duis iaculis vestibulum quam. Sed cursus dolor eget
      dui interdum, ac vestibulum ipsum blandit. In suscipit neque vitae
      malesuada rutrum. Vivamus quis mauris mi. Nunc tristique arcu gravida
      neque commodo, eu facilisis augue tempus. Pellentesque habitant morbi
      tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nam
      scelerisque nisl id est semper, vel mollis massa iaculis. Integer eu
      tortor vitae nisi pharetra elementum vel eget quam. Donec facilisis, risus
      et tristique sollicitudin, est est feugiat nibh, dapibus consectetur nibh
      ligula eget erat. Mauris venenatis sodales lectus, id auctor ligula
      posuere condimentum. Integer et nulla et enim lacinia scelerisque at in
      dui. Donec nec massa nisi. Donec diam mauris, hendrerit ut sem et,
      malesuada varius eros. Nam blandit tempor erat, nec congue augue
      consectetur at. Nam viverra dictum elementum. Mauris malesuada ipsum eget
      enim posuere, id consequat mi eleifend. Aenean feugiat diam in orci
      sagittis pellentesque. Nunc gravida condimentum ipsum, a pretium erat
      egestas et. Curabitur tempus convallis neque sollicitudin volutpat. Ut
      lacinia, mi lobortis vehicula egestas, nibh lorem pretium odio, nec
      feugiat augue turpis quis purus. Morbi maximus congue lacus, ac tempus
      enim viverra ac. Ut quis efficitur dui. Suspendisse sagittis justo non
      enim vulputate volutpat. Nunc sollicitudin lectus eget varius venenatis.
      Morbi elementum imperdiet eros, vel suscipit ex mattis vel. Morbi ipsum
      libero, iaculis vitae orci in, feugiat euismod lacus. Ut molestie et nibh
      non vehicula. Mauris vitae justo risus. Nam orci mi, volutpat quis
      vestibulum sed, consequat vel nibh. Mauris nec ultricies dui, eu lacinia
      mi. Ut quis ex sit amet metus luctus vestibulum. Cras at accumsan mi.
      Proin quis sagittis augue. Proin eget convallis est, non suscipit tortor.
      Pellentesque libero purus, efficitur vel egestas vel, dictum vel eros.
      <br />
      <br />
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary"
        (click)="toggleNestedScrollbar()"
      >
        Toggle nested scrollbar
      </button>
    </div>
    <div
      class="col-3 showcase-course-content-sidebar"
      id="shepherd-body-showcase-course-content-sidebar"
    >
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```